# How to keep an activity alive while closing all the others in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a main activity that contains a drawer and then i have other activities that opens on top of it they also have the drawer menu(they inherit main activity)

```
public class OBDActivity  extends MainActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_setting, null, false);
    mDrawer.addView(contentView, 0);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.OBDParams);
 }
 ...
}
```

I want to keep the main activity alive and kill all of the other activities when a new activity is being opened?

I already tried this but it just kill the old activity that is the same activity that is being opened.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, MessagesActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

In fact I want to start new Activity and finish current one either its the same activity or a different type.

Comment: did you mean that if Activity A(MainActivity) --> B --> C --> D --> E than B,C,D will be destroy  ? and after i click back button will redirect to A?

Comment: do you call `finish()`?

Comment: @ND1010_ yes, exactly.

Comment: @Mr.Rabbit I need to keep the main activity open.

Comment: I am asking to write `finish()` when you move from any activity other than your `MainActivity`. In this case, your `MainActivity` doesn't get destroyed since you are neither calling `finish()` nor you're using any flags. While when you move from any other activites (B, C or D) it gets destroyed since you're calling `finish()`. Your `MainActivity` always remains on top.

Comment: @Mr.Rabbit The thing is i'm starting other activities from the drawer that has been defined once in main activity.

Comment: @MahboobehMohammadi Try to set the `launchMode` for all the other activities except your `MainActivity` as `singleInstance` inside your manifest file.

Comment: @Mr.Rabbit nope! still stays open! I want it closed when other activity starts

Comment: @Mr.Rabbit I simply wants to close current activity when a new one opens but the thing is current activity inherits mainactivity so i cant use finish cause it finishes mainactivity

Comment: which activity do you want to keep, MainActivity?

Comment: @niveshshastri yes. imagine i open B activity and the A activity was opened before , now i want to keep main activity and B activity and close A activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i could do this was to handle closing old `activity` by myself so i kept a reference of the `activity` that was opening and close it when a new one was going to open.

I created a variable named `oldActivity` in my `Main Activity` and i set it in each and every other activities `onCreate` method :

```
 openedActivity = this;
```

Then whenever another `activity` was going to open from drawer menu i just finished the old one:

```
  oldActivity.finish();
```

Comment: Not a good solution. keeping references to activities prevents the garbage collector from cleaning them up. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your `MainActivity` as a "dispatcher". When you want to open `MessagesActivity`, do this:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
// Add an extra that specifies the name of the class that should be started by MainActivity
intent.putExtra("startActivity", MessagesActivity.class.getName());
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear the activity stack all the way back to your existing instance of `MainActivity`.

Now, in `MainActivity`, override `onNewIntent()` and take care of dispatching to the desired `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Check if we should launch another Activity
    if (intent.hasExtra("startActivity") {
        // Start the desired Activity
        String activityName = intent.getStringExtra("startActivity");
        Intent dispatchIntent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(activityName));
        startActivity(dispatchIntent);
    }
}
```

This will launch the desired `Activity` on top of `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityC.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

For More about [intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 0):

*No, You cannot do this using common Flags of activities or any function.Not certainly of my knowledge*

But there is one workaround for it , you can clear all activities from backstack and then reopen the first one.

**Try This:**

```
Intent intents = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```