# Is there any way to keep a reference of an instance of a activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there any way to keep a reference of an instance of a activity?

Imagine i have below code :

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, OBDActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);

    Activity openedActiviy = ????
```

Now I want to keep the instance of the OBDActivity that was opened somewhere cause I want to finish it later. instead of OBDActivity  it could be any other activity, in fact I want to have a variable that keeps the last opened activity.

```
openedActiviy.finish();
```

any idea ?

Comment: you should not ever keep a reference to an activity in a field

Comment: Based on one of your comments in an answer, you are going about trying to solve the wrong problem. If you want to clear certain activities from the stack, then you need to use the correct combination of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. This should solve your problem without resorting to hacks like telling other activities to exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **BroadcastReceiver** when any activity finishes

1. Implement broadcast receiver

   ```
   BroadcastReceiver myBroadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //here you can finish activity or whatever you want.
      }
   };
   ```
2. Register broadcast receiver

   ```
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.test.MY_ACTION"));
   ```
3. Send broadcast when activity finishes

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent("com.test.MY_ACTION");
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).sendBroadcast(i);
   ```

Comment: this is very bad practice

Comment: why do you tell him to use this if you know it's bad?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I answered what he had asked, so no more comments, OK???

Comment: sure, but you are pointing him in the wrong direction with this answer. You should just explain him the better way instead

Comment: @TimCastelijns  I'm a her guys!

Comment: Great, but I had not downvoted it, so I can't change anything

Comment: No issue, everyone has the right to upvote and downvote

Comment: I think it should be
`3. Send broadcast when you want the activity to finish`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Broadcasts. You register broadcast receiver in the new activity and you send broadcast from the previous. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html

Answer (score 1):

this is a bad idea to keep refrence of an activity . it may cause memory leak.
Instead You can use Broadcast listener in your activity.

```
private class ProgressBroadCast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(some_condition){
        finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use this refrence for this problem, i dont know if Broadcast listener will come to use there. would you please take a look here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403448/how-to-keep-an-activity-alive-while-closing-all-the-others-in-android/46405451#46405451